# Escrever em um arquivo CSV

Tags: python, csv

Preciso que meu *script* escreva em um arquivo CSV. O mesmo irá abrir um arquivo CSV que possui a coluna `created_at` (data e horário), após isso, a variável será "quebrada" e será escrito em um novo arquivo CSV a coluna dia e hora. Porém, está apresentando erro ao tentar escrever no arquivo (`writer.writerows(dia,hora)`); apresenta mensagem de erro :

> TypeError: writerows() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Segue código:

```
import csv
import re
import os

fin = open('teste.csv', 'r')

fout = open('teste2.csv', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

with open(os.path.join('teste2.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['dia','hora'], delimiter = ',')
    writer.writeheader()



for row in reader:
    data = row['created_at'].split("T")[0]
    dia = data.split("-")[2]

    horario = row['created_at'].split("T")[1]
    hora= horario.split(":")[0]

    writer.writerows([dia,hora])  

fin.close() 
fout.close()
```

Comment: Após alteração para: writer.writerows([dia,hora]) apresenta a seguinte mensagem : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Teste\teste.py", line 25, in <module>
    writer.writerows([dia,hora])  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 157, in writerows
    rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '1', '9'

Comment: Edit sua questão e adicione um fragmento (as 10 primeiras linhas, por exemplo) do arquivo csv que vc tem que ler, e a ultima mensagem de erro que esta ocorrendo.

Answer (score 3):

Em `writer.writerows([dia,hora])` voce está tentando gravar uma lista e `csv.DictWriter` espera um dicionário.
Sem conhecer o conteúdo do seu arquivo de entrada, Fiz uma adptação do seu código e gerei o *teste2.csv* de acordo com o que voce especificou. Para isso criei um csv com o seguinte conteúdo:

### teste.csv

```
created_at
01-02-17 01:55:00
01-02-17 02:55:00
01-03-17 03:00:55
01-04-17 04:55:00
```

Nesse arquivo há somente um header para a data/horário da criação, e as duas informações estão separadas por um espaço, como seria a conversão de `timestamp` para `string` em python. O codigo abaixo vai ler desse arquivo e gravar em **teste2.csv**, porém com 2 headers, um para o dia e outro para a hora.

### Código

```
import csv
import re
import os

fin = open('teste.csv', 'r')

fout = open('teste2.csv', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

with open(os.path.join('teste2.csv'), 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['dia','hora'], delimiter = ',')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        list_dh = row['created_at'].split(' ')
        dh = dict(dia=list_dh[0], hora=list_dh[1])
        writer.writerow(dh)    

fin.close() 
fout.close()
```

### Resultado

```
dia,hora
01-02-17,01:55:00
01-02-17,02:55:00
01-03-17,03:00:55
01-04-17,04:55:00
```

Comment: Olá, alterando para writer.writerow({'dia': dia, 'hora': hora}) o mesmo executou corretamente. Obrigada!